# Ошибка связывания таблиц: can't write unknown attribute `option_id`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Я сделал так:

Модель Post

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :option
accepts_nested_attributes_for :option
end
```

Модель Option

```
class Option < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :post
end
```

В котроллер Post прописал ассоц обьект

```
@post.option = Option.new
```

Так же в param вписал свое поле в таблице option_attributes: [:test1]

```
params.require(:post).permit(:title, option_attributes: [:test1])
```

Во вьюс вставил так

```
<%= f.fields_for :option do |o|%>
<%= o.text_field :test1 %>
<% end %>
```

Но при заходе на post/new получаю ошибку

> can't write unknown attribute `option_id`

в строке

**@post.option = Option.new**

**UDP**
Сейчас все получилось
При добавлении Post/new поля test1
Оно записывается в option

Но появилась странность.

```
К примеру я добавил пост, вписал в test1 "привет"
В базе пост появился с **option_id = 1**
А таблице option создалась запись с полем test1 "Привет" **и id 1**

Далее я нажал редактировать запись и изменил "Привет" на "Пока"
В таблице post данной новости option_id сменился **на id 2**

А в таблице option создалась вторая запись с полем test1 "Пока" и **id 2**
При этом первая осталась с id1 и Привет.
И так далее, если отредактировать еще раз появиться третья.
```

Как сделать так что бы при редактировании она не создавала новую в option а просто редактировала существующую?

**UDP**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @post = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
@post = Post.new
@post.option = Option.new
end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, option_attributes: [:test1])

    end
end
```

Comment: Если убрать воду: у вас есть модель Post и модель Option (привести относящийся код классов), и вы хотите в форме `new` для Post заполнять ассоциированный Option. Всё так?

Comment: Да все верно, я сейчас поправлю пост для вас, секунду

Comment: Готово поправил

Comment: А вы добавили поле option_id к таблице posts?

Comment: Упс, видно мне пора спать) у меня была названа таблица options_id

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, еще один момент если вам не трудно. Сейчас поправлю пост секунду.

Comment: Да, конечно, помогу чем смогу:)

Comment: Спасибо, очень благодарен вам за ответы, они для меня очень важны, так как только осваиваюсь. Поправил пост

Comment: Покажите код контроллера, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Конечно) добавил в пост

Comment: Тут явно косяк в том что для post применяется update при изменении поста. А для option применяется опять create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что `post_params` в `option_attributes` не пропускается поле :id. Поэтому рельсы думают, что вы хотите связать новый объект с `Post`.

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, option_attributes: [:id, :test1])
end
```

И я бы еще посоветовал сделать Post has_one :option. Так мне кажеться логичнее :)

Comment: Спасибо :)))))) Все заработало, я только об этом думал.

Comment: Даже не знаю как выразить благодарность. Очень благодарен что не прошли мимо и подсказали :)

Comment: Не за что, просто даже самому интересно было, вроде с виду все правильно, но почему то не работает :)